# How to track JTA transactions

Tags: spring, logging, jta, atomikos

We have JTA transactions(Atomikos) configured using Spring annotations across different places in our application. I need to get trace logs whenever a transaction started and completed.

For example, whenever the below method invoked within a new transaction,

```
@Transactional
void createAgent() { ... }
```

I need to log a message saying

```
Transaction started on AgentFactory::createAgent() ...
Transaction ended on AgentFactory::createAgent() ...
```

Can you please provide if there is any way to enable trace logging on transactions?

Answer (score 0):

If you set loglevel to DEBUG or TRACE for org.springframework.transaction

you get the log entries you want. May be not in the exact format, but the information is provided.